# How to stop flv video player from playing when open another frame/page

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs6, flashplayer-9

Hi I'm new with adobe flash player CS6 action script. My problem is when I click another page / frame the video player keep playing. I use XML to load the video.

This is my code snippets

```
 stop();

import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlloaded);

var xml:XML = new XML();
var amountofvid:Number=0;
var currentvideo:Number=0;

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,prevvid);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nextvid);

function xmlloaded(e:Event){
    xml=XML(e.target.data);
    amountofvid=xml.video.length()-1;
    changevid();
    }

function nextvid(e:Event){
    currentvideo++;
    changevid();
    }

    function prevvid(e:Event){
        currentvideo--;
        changevid();
        }

function changevid():void{
    var cv:Number=Math.abs(currentvideo);


    if(cv>amountofvid){

        currentvideo=cv=0;
        }

        if(currentvideo<0){

            currentvideo=cv=amountofvid;
            }
    vid.source=xml.video.@src[cv];
    }

loader.load(new URLRequest('video.xml'));
```

Please any helps, thank you

Comment: XML loading routine is **totally** irrelevant. You shouldn't have mentioned it at all. The only useful line in your script is **vid.source = ...** You should go to official Adobe documentation (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/), find the video playback class you are using as **vid** and figure a method to call to stop it. As far as Adobe developers are usually sane, the method will be called **stop** or maybe **pause**.

Comment: Hi thank you, just got the solution. I put this

flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll();

And stop the video from playing

Comment: It's a peg leg of a solution. This command stops all the currently playing sound channels, but is does not really stops the video, which is detached from display list yet keeps playing somewhere where you cannot see it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry putting flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll(); that was very bad solution, because it will kills all sound, my solution is by putting event

```
vid.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, stopPlay);
function stopPlay(e:Event)
{
      vid.stop();
}
```

This works correct as this link explanation

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/773601

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Solution I put this code in the beginning of frame

```
flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll();
```